# Select hibernate + ifrebird

Tags: java, firebird

Pessoal estou com erro na hr de fazer os select !!! segue a classe e o erro

```
Advertência:   #{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
javax.faces.FacesException: #{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
    at DAO.GestorDAO.buscaPorId(GestorDAO.java:29)
    at Controller.mbeanUsuario.Vusuario(mbeanUsuario.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 558
.
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:135)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBPreparedStatement.<init>(FBPreparedStatement.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatementFactory.createPreparedStatement(FBStatementFactory.java:89)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:1135)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:890)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:844)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 558
.
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2092)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2042)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlPrepare(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1465)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSHelper.prepareStatement(GDSHelper.java:195)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractStatement.java:1401)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:1261)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:132)
    ... 77 more

FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException obtido durante o processamento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=#{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
FATAL:   #{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
javax.faces.FacesException: #{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
    at DAO.GestorDAO.buscaPorId(GestorDAO.java:29)
    at Controller.mbeanUsuario.Vusuario(mbeanUsuario.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 558
.
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:135)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBPreparedStatement.<init>(FBPreparedStatement.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatementFactory.createPreparedStatement(FBStatementFactory.java:89)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:1135)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:890)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:844)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 558
.
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2092)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2042)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlPrepare(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1465)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSHelper.prepareStatement(GDSHelper.java:195)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractStatement.java:1401)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:1261)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:132)
    ... 77 more
```

segue o entity

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="CADGRU")
public class Cadgru implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "GT_CADGRU_CODGRU", allocationSize = 1 )  

    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ" )  
     private String codgru;

     private String nomgru;
     private String nomfan;
     private String serial;
     private int numloj;
     private String email;
     private String endsrv;
     private int prtsrv;
     private int tipcob;
     private String observ;
     private Date datven;
     private String oldEndsrv;
     private String endfdb;
     private String ondaEndsrv;
     private Integer numsrv;
     private String ipInt;
     private int tipsis;

    /**
     * @return the codgru
     */
    public String getCodgru() {
        return codgru;
    }

    /**
     * @param codgru the codgru to set
     */
    public void setCodgru(String codgru) {
        this.codgru = codgru;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nomgru
     */
    public String getNomgru() {
        return nomgru;
    }

    /**
     * @param nomgru the nomgru to set
     */
    public void setNomgru(String nomgru) {
        this.nomgru = nomgru;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nomfan
     */
    public String getNomfan() {
        return nomfan;
    }

    /**
     * @param nomfan the nomfan to set
     */
    public void setNomfan(String nomfan) {
        this.nomfan = nomfan;
    }

    /**
     * @return the serial
     */
    public String getSerial() {
        return serial;
    }

    /**
     * @param serial the serial to set
     */
    public void setSerial(String serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numloj
     */
    public int getNumloj() {
        return numloj;
    }

    /**
     * @param numloj the numloj to set
     */
    public void setNumloj(int numloj) {
        this.numloj = numloj;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the endsrv
     */
    public String getEndsrv() {
        return endsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @param endsrv the endsrv to set
     */
    public void setEndsrv(String endsrv) {
        this.endsrv = endsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @return the prtsrv
     */
    public int getPrtsrv() {
        return prtsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @param prtsrv the prtsrv to set
     */
    public void setPrtsrv(int prtsrv) {
        this.prtsrv = prtsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tipcob
     */
    public int getTipcob() {
        return tipcob;
    }

    /**
     * @param tipcob the tipcob to set
     */
    public void setTipcob(int tipcob) {
        this.tipcob = tipcob;
    }

    /**
     * @return the observ
     */
    public String getObserv() {
        return observ;
    }

    /**
     * @param observ the observ to set
     */
    public void setObserv(String observ) {
        this.observ = observ;
    }

    /**
     * @return the datven
     */
    public Date getDatven() {
        return datven;
    }

    /**
     * @param datven the datven to set
     */
    public void setDatven(Date datven) {
        this.datven = datven;
    }

    /**
     * @return the oldEndsrv
     */
    public String getOldEndsrv() {
        return oldEndsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @param oldEndsrv the oldEndsrv to set
     */
    public void setOldEndsrv(String oldEndsrv) {
        this.oldEndsrv = oldEndsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @return the endfdb
     */
    public String getEndfdb() {
        return endfdb;
    }

    /**
     * @param endfdb the endfdb to set
     */
    public void setEndfdb(String endfdb) {
        this.endfdb = endfdb;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ondaEndsrv
     */
    public String getOndaEndsrv() {
        return ondaEndsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @param ondaEndsrv the ondaEndsrv to set
     */
    public void setOndaEndsrv(String ondaEndsrv) {
        this.ondaEndsrv = ondaEndsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numsrv
     */
    public Integer getNumsrv() {
        return numsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @param numsrv the numsrv to set
     */
    public void setNumsrv(Integer numsrv) {
        this.numsrv = numsrv;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ipInt
     */
    public String getIpInt() {
        return ipInt;
    }

    /**
     * @param ipInt the ipInt to set
     */
    public void setIpInt(String ipInt) {
        this.ipInt = ipInt;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tipsis
     */
    public int getTipsis() {
        return tipsis;
    }

    /**
     * @param tipsis the tipsis to set
     */
    public void setTipsis(int tipsis) {
        this.tipsis = tipsis;
    }

    /**
     * @return the codgru
     */


}
```

segue o DAO

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import Entity.Cadgru;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
@Stateless
public class GestorDAO   {

    public Cadgru buscaPorId (String gr) {
        Cadgru grupo = new Cadgru();
        EntityManager em = Conexao.getEntityManager();

                EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
                tx.begin();

                Query q = em.createQuery ("from Cadgru where codgru ='" + gr + "'");
                grupo = (Cadgru) q.getSingleResult();

                tx.commit();

                em.close();



        return grupo;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente o problema está na linha

```
Query q = em.createQuery ("from Cadgru where codgru ='" + gr + "'");
```

pois o erro é um `SQLGrammarException` (gramática incorreta do *statement*).

Imagino que você queira selecionar uma linha da tabela, sendo que nesse caso estaria faltando `SELECT *` no início do *statement*, então o correto seria algo como

```
Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT * from Cadgru where codgru ='" + gr + "'");
```

OBS.: Também é importante destacar que `q.getSingleResult()` não deve retornar um `CadGru`, mas sim uma `String`, a qual você deveria usar para criar criar um `CadGru`.